# What is freebiespro.co.uk doing in my /var/log/apache2/access.log?

Tags: security, apache-http-server

I am totally beginner in apache, but I've noticed that there is a line in my `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

```
GET http://www.freebiespro.co.uk/getip.php HTTP/1.0
```

from a Chinese IP `222.215.230.175`

I live in Europe.

I've just started the server (in 15 minutes).

What is this doing in my log? Am I pwnd? Why are chinese people/bots accessing my server? How does he know that I exist?

Comment: You host a public server, so you need to live with that.

Comment: Somebody is just blindly scanning for proxies, nothing to be worried about (unless you have enabled forward proxy mode by setting `ProxyRequests On`). You however need to take good care when running a server on the internet. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/security_tips.html is a good point to start reading.

Comment: Is www.freebiespro.co.uk _your_ web site?

Comment: @lgarzo, no it's not!

Answer (score 2):

You will get all kinds of bots and scans from all over the Internet. That's what happens when you have your server exposed to the Internet. You can configure Apache to not allow access from certain countries based on IP addresses if you like, and you can configure it to tell nice bots to not scan you.

He knows you exist because he probably started scanning your IP block and found your server.

Google is your friend, putting a server on the Internet comes with a lot of security concerns outside the scope of this forum.